# How can I pass JSON animation file from Internal Storage instead of the Assets folder?

Tags: android, animation, assets, lottie

How can I pass JSON animation file from Internal Storage instead of Assets folder in Lottie animation view?

Answer (score 2):

Lottie Library only set JSON file from assets folder using fileName attribute.
For Instance:

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
    android:id="@+id/anim_iv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:lottie_fileName="sample.json"
    app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
    app:lottie_loop="true"
    app:lottie_imageAssetsFolder="images"
    />
```

If you tried to set JSON file from Internal or external storage, than it would not work. You have to load all JSON data from JSON file in string and set it to LottieAnimationView using setAnimationFromJson() method, like this-

```
 LottieCompositionFactory.fromJsonString(json,getString(R.string.app_name)).addListener(new LottieListener<LottieComposition>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(LottieComposition result) {
            animView.setComposition(result);
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

You would want something along the lines of

```
File TEST = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "TEST");
TEST.mkdir(); // make directory may want to check return value
String path = TEST.getAbsolutePath(); // get absolute path
```

and permissions

```
<manifest ...>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
...
</manifest>
```

Comment: I have already tried this but got this error =>
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find file /storage/emulated/0/blast.json

Comment: ok,if you need you can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I have already provided the required permissions,
I got the access of file but unable to pass it to Lottie animation.